# Why these radio buttons aren't displaying with proper alignment when small screen

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I add radio input fields & labels in bootstrap.Radio buttons **display fine on large screen**.But if the **screen size get minimize** then **radio button get out of the screen**.
Please check image given below:

[image]

please suggest me about bringing  proper alignment back.
Here is the source code:

```js
function updateBill(type) {
  var id = "bill";
  document.getElementById(id).value = document.getElementById(type).value;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading"></div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="employeeid">ID:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"  aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="employeeid" placeholder="Enter ID">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group form-inline row">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;">Quantity:</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="radio ">
                <input class="radio-inline" type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio0" value="0" onchange="updateBill('radio0')" checked>
                <label class="radio-inline">None</label>
                <input class="radio-inline" type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio1" value="200" onchange="updateBill('radio1')">
                <label class="radio-inline">One</label>
                <input class="radio-inline" type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio2" value="300" onchange="updateBill('radio2')">
                <label class="radio-inline">Two</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;">Bill:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"  aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" id="bill" placeholder=".00">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

please let me know if any further information is required.
Thanks :)

Comment: default radio button icon wont resize at all, you need to set a custom icon in order to make it responsive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML structure needs to be adjusted as your using multiple types of form classes, using `radio-inline` on the input and the label and should have the radios inside a column like the rest of your inputs. See [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#inline-checkboxes-and-radios).

See working example Snippet.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading"></div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="employeeid">ID:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"  aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="employeeid" placeholder="Enter ID">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Quantity:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio0" value="0" onchange="updateBill('radio0')" checked>None
              </label>
              <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio1" value="200" onchange="updateBill('radio1')">One
              </label>
              <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio2" value="300" onchange="updateBill('radio2')">Two
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;">Bill:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"  aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" id="bill" placeholder=".00">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The parent *div* `radio` that you used was causing this issue.

I change the name to `radio-group` and added a `margin-left` to it like so:

```
.radio-group {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1aL52bjb/)

The element with class name `radio` was causing the issue because it is an existing class in bootstrap and therefore some CSS were being applied that moves the radio button off the grid.

Answer (score 1):

i hope this will solve your problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Radio Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <form role="form">
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 3</label>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading"></div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="employeeid">ID:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"  aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="employeeid" placeholder="Enter ID">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
<!--// ************          MODIFIED SECTION **************** //-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="employeeid">Quantity:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <div class="radio">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio0" value="0" onchange="updateBill('radio0')" checked>
                None
              </label>

              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio1" value="200" onchange="updateBill('radio1')">
                One
              </label>
               <label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio2" value="300" onchange="updateBill('radio2')">
                Two
              </label>
            </div>


            </div>
          </div>
<!--// ************          MODIFIED SECTION  ENDS**************** //-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;">Bill:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"  aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" id="bill" placeholder=".00">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

You have used unnecessary styles on the "Quantity" section. Removed the class `class="radio-inline"`, added div with `<div class="col-sm-8">`, will make it work. Have a look into the updated code within **MODIFIED SECTION**